# Volatility Breakout Strategy in TradingView PineScript v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

In TradingView, I implemented long and short strategies according to the volatility breakthrough strategy with PineScript. However, it seems that there are times when the backtest results are slightly different from the actual results. Is there any solution for this???

In addition, it was set so that only one contract was signed unconditionally, but in some cases, there are times when two contracts are entered. I thought this was when switching long and short in Pinescript, but it wasn't. The script doesn't seem to understand the current number of contracts for longs and shorts.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsVb8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ5Nd.png)

Is it possible to implement it in Pinescript exactly like the actual transaction without repaint?